# Calculating the $L_{\infty}$ regressionin Matlab

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, matlab, regression

I have the following problem: suppose, I have IID $(x_t,y_t)$ variable, where let's  say $t=1,...,N$.

My task is to solve the following optimization problem:

$$\min_{\theta=[\theta_1,...,\theta_q]} \max_{t=1,...,N} |y_t-f(x_t)^T \theta|$$

I have looked up a bunch of articles about the $L_\infty$ regression and how to implement it in Matlab, and I am convinced that I need to use the CVX package.

I would be more then happy if I could solve this following example: let us have $x_1=1, x_2=2, x_3=3, y_1=0, y_2=1, y_3=2$.

What do I need to plot if I want to solve this polynomial problem?

$$\min_{\theta=[\theta_1,\theta_2]} \max_{t=1,2,3} |y_t-(\theta_1+\theta_2x_t)|$$

I have tried the following but I cant really progress:

X = [
    0
    1
    2
    ];

Y = [
    1
    2
    3
    ];

cvx_begin
variable A
minimize(norm(Y-A+A*X,inf))
cvx_end

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = [0 1 2]';
Y = [1 2 3]';
cvx_begin
variable theta(2)
minimize(norm(Y - [ones(3,1) X]*theta,inf))
cvx_end
```

The optimal solution to your example is `theta = [1 1]'`, which produces optimal objective value of zero, because there is a perfect fit. And in this example, this theta would be optimal for any norm, not just inf.

But for instance, if `Y` were instead `[1 4 2]'`, there is no perfect fit with this functional form, and the optimal `theta` for the `1, 2, and inf` norms would respectively be [`1 0.5]', [1.833 0.5]', [2.25 0.5]'`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you perhaps generalize the solution, if the thing we want to maximize is  a higher degree polynomial, like $\theta_1+\theta_2 x_t + \theta_3 x_t^2+\theta_4 x_t^3$?

Comment: Also: I am not really familiar with plots. Is there a nice way to plot the solutions here? :)

Comment: Generalization up to cubic term:    
    variable theta(4);
    minimize(norm(Y - [ones(3,1) X X.^2 X.^3]*theta,inf))

As for plotting, that is really a MATLAB matter, not a math question. You can plot Y or the residuals vs. the optimal fitted polynomial.

Comment: Thank you for your time, i will accept the answer.